# Documentation generator for gherkin feature files

Tags: gherkin

I have several VS projects with many gherkin feature files distributed among them.Is there a way to view all the feature files via say a url in the browser? I dont want someone to have to download any tool or checkout code from a repository.
   I did research and Pickles claims to be doing what i want.Are there any examples showing the integration of pickles with say VS projects?Any help is appreciated.thanks!